# Best way to parse JSON data into a table using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have document stored in database that holds the employees schedule for the week, which looks like so:

```
[ { _id: 55c407dc8ce6dfd4103c15db,
    'Last, First':
     { 'Mon   7/27': '10:15a-8:00p',
       'Wed   7/29': '10:15a-8:00p',
       'Fri   7/31': '10:30a-8:00p' },
    'Doe, John':
     { 'Tue   7/28': '2:00p-11:30p',
       'Thu   7/30': '8:00a-5:30p',
       'Sat   8/1': '10:15a-8:00p' }]
```

and then in my main page I have it load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  populateTable();
  ...}

function populateTable() {
$.getJSON('/download/download', function(data) {
 ???
}
```

The get Json works great and get the document perfectly.  However, I'm not sure the best way to parse the information into a html table. Ideally I would want the table to look like this:

```
              Mon 7/27     Tue 7/28     Wed 7/29     Thu 7/30    Fri 7/31   Sat 8/1   Sun 8/2
Last, First  10:15a-8:00p             10:15a-8:00p
Doe, John                 2:00p-11:30p              8:00a-5:30p          10:15a-8:00p
```

I was wondering what the best way would be to do this within the populateTable() function.  I am using jade for views and have the table set as so, but was wondering what the best way to append to it would be.

```
div.container
  div.content
    #mainTable
       table.table.table-striped
       thead
         tr
div.footer
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? Simply create a row for each person, and insert it into the table: [jQuery Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as an implementation for `populateTable()` I'd do the following:

1. Look at are which columns I'd need. Probably by looping through each employee in `data`, making a list of all the dates they are working.
2. Create the row of headers by starting with an empty `td` and then creating a `th` for each date that anyone was working (created in step 1)
3. Create a row for each employee, and for each day checking to see if their object in the JSON had a value for that day. If they did, output a `td` with their times, otherwise output an empty `td`.

That's the general scheme of how I'd go about designing `populateTable()`